# Convert TJpegImage to byte array

Tags: delphi

I am implementing webcam functionality in a client/server, and I am sending/receiving each frame over the socket as a JPEG.  In order to do this, I am converting the JPEG into a byte array and then sending it.  The server receives it as a byte array and converts it to a JPEG.

My question is how to convert the JPEG to a byte array (and vice versa) efficiently.

The way that I'm doing it now seems like it's probably not ideal.  I'm currently creating a TMemoryStream, saving the JPEG into it, and then reading the stream into a byte array.  Then on the server side, once it receives the array, I'm creating a TMemoryStream, writing the array into it, and then creating a TJpegImage and loading the stream into it.

It seems like my way requires a lot of steps, and memory allocations.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for a conversion, you can directly save a jpeg image to a stream , transfer the stream, and load the jpeg from a stream.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.SaveToStream  :  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.LoadFromStream  ...for reference

Comment: Agreed, especially since the `TMemoryStream.Memory` block of data can be directly treated as a byte array of `TMemoryStream.Size` length (just don't treat it as a **dynamic** array, because it is not).

Comment: Thank you.  Is the `TMemoryStream.Memory` not read-only though?  I'm not using a sockets library that has a 'ReceiveStream' method, so how should I approach the situation on the receiving end?

Comment: As far as I don't know which libraray you are using I have to guess that something like FMyMemoryStream.Write(Buf^,DataLen); should work with your components